# Pass datatable as parameter to a stored procedure to perform update

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I need pass the whole table to a stored procedure to run a update query.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UploadData] AS TABLE
(
    [CODE] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [SERIALNUMBER] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PRODUCTCODE] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [THRESHOLD] [int] NULL  
)
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateExchangeThreshold
    @TableType dbo.UploadData READONLY 

   UPDATE [dbo].[ExchangeData_20221213] 
   SET t.Threshold = tbl.THRESHOLD
   FROM [dbo].[ExchangeData_20221213] t
   INNER JOIN @TableType AS tbl ON t.ProductCode = tbl.PRODUCTCODE 
                                AND t.SerialNumber = tbl.SERIALNUMBER
```

In my VB.Net code, I have this:

```
Using sqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    sqlCommand.Connection = connection
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "sp_UpdateExchangeThreshold"
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 180
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim parameterList As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@TableType", SqlDbType.Structured)
    parameterList.Value = dataTable
    parameterList.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterList)

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

I'm not able to update the records. Any mistake I made? Please help

Comment: You cannot use a variable as table name. You will need to use `Dynamic SQL` for it to work

Comment: @Squirrel any reference can share with me?

Comment: do a search for `dynamic sql`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @Squirrel thats not dynamic SQL is it? OP is just referencing the table variable parameter which is passed into the SP? I think anyway :) please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BubbleBub pretty sure you need to specify the type of the table variable you are passing in. For example this is my C# code which will be similar `SqlParameter tableParam = new SqlParameter("@TableType", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "dbo.UpdateData" };`

Comment: @DaleK I have add typename but also not update the records.  This is my code     
      Dim parameterList As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@TQMSTableType", 
     SqlDbType.Structured)
                        parameterList.Value = dataTable
                        parameterList.TypeName = "dbo.TQMSUploadExcelData"
                        parameterList.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterList)

Comment: When you debug and put a breakpoint on the execute command is there data in your datatable?

Comment: Ya, the datatable pass in have value.  The Column name of the datatable also same as the define type name.  I have if....else in my stored procedure.  In my VB.Net code, I add sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BATCHUPDATE", 1)

Comment: You don't need ANY parameter's to send a data table with changes back to the database, see my post below how this works.

Comment: Is that a typo? Your stored proc definition does not have the AS after @TableType dbo.UploadData READONLY.  Also to see if your TableType has data, you can issue a select * into TEMP_TableType from TableType inside your stored proc to see if it really does contain data. (Had to remove the @ sign. SO complains that I can only notify one post owner at a time)

Comment: If you use Dapper then you can use the `AsTableValuedParameter` extension method to do this easily

Comment: I select my @TableType and it contain the data I passing in from code behind

Comment: My bad. @DaleK you are correct.

Comment: Does the SP work as expected when you run it entirely in SSMS? It *looks* OK on the face of it. Also are the datatype definitions identical in your `dbo.UploadData` table as your `[dbo].[ExchangeData_20221213]` table?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a .NET ADO datatable is NOT a SQL Server table type. They have NOHTING to do with each other. You can use a datatable with Oracle, MySQL, or any server based system. You can even use a access database with a data table.

So, datatable object is platform gnostic (neutral), and thus can't be passed, used as a SQL table type.

However, you don't really have to pass  a table back. The REAL question is what do you want to do with this table?

Do you want to edit, or update or insert rows from that table back into the database?

If yes, then use a table adaptor (that's what they are for).

Not only will they do all the dirty work for you, but that table can have updates, deletes, edits and insert/additions.

And with ONE command you can send that WHOLE table + all edit/update/delete/adds in one shot.

Say like this:

```
    Dim rstHotels As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsD"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            ' delete first row
            rstData.Rows(0).Delete()    ' delete first row

            rstData.Rows(2).Item("City") = "Zoo" ' edit/modify the 3rd row

            Dim OneNewRow As DataRow = rstData.NewRow

            OneNewRow("FirstName") = "First Name"
            OneNewRow("LastName") = "last Name"
            OneNewRow("HotelName") = "My Hotel Name"
            OneNewRow("Active") = True

            rstData.Rows.Add(OneNewRow)

            ' now, lets send edits/delete/inserts back to database.
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

            da.Update(rstData)

        End Using
    End Using
```

Now, I have the load the table and the update as per above, but they can be done separately.

**Edit: Sending the datatable to SQL Server, but not all rows.**

```
    ' so, lets "send" to the sql database some data
    Dim rstData2 As New DataTable
    rstData2.Columns.Add("HotelName", GetType(String))
    rstData2.Columns.Add("City")     ' FYI -- defualt is string 
    rstData2.Columns.Add("Active", GetType(Boolean))

    ' lets create 5 test rows of data
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim MyNewRow As DataRow = rstData2.NewRow
        MyNewRow("HotelName") = "Hotel #" & i
        MyNewRow("City") = "City #" & i
        MyNewRow("Active") = True   ' you MUST include columnes that require deffault value
        rstData2.Rows.Add(MyNewRow)
    Next


    ' now send in one shot to database
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Active FROM tblHotelsD"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData2)
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: The datatable have a data from excel file which user amend some data.  I need to update it back to database.  I know I can loop through the datatable and update one by one.  Just need to know how I can pass the whole data table as parameter to store procedure and update at store procedure.

Comment: You can't pass as a parameter, but you CAN send the whole table as a single update as above shows. As long as the data table matches the sql table, then you can send the whole table back to SQL server in one single da.Update(mytable) command. In other words, you don't even need a store proc, and you can't use a parameter anyway. However, do you see any parameter's in above? (nope!!!). So, you kill multiple birds with one stone, save money having to write/use a store proc, and better you don't even need to write and use parameter's (saving even more world poverty).

Comment: my data table just have few column while the sql table have more column.  So, it's not work?  And how I can send whole table to sql data adapter to update one go for all data in the data table?

Comment: don't matter, as long as the data table you have at least matches the few columns you have in the datatable, then you good to go. It not clear if you adding/inserting, or you need to update. Of course if you updating, then you need a PK in those rows, but you don't need the PK if you just adding rows to the table, and then sending the whole table back to SQL server in one shot.

Comment: See my edit - I show how I just created a data table, add some rows, and then send it off to SQL server in one update.

Comment: But your data table do not have ID, how sql data adapter know which record to update

Comment: If you just adding rows to the target table, then you don't care. However, if there is a need to update a row by some PK value, then yes, you have to supply the PK.  If you don't have a PK, then we might have to do a bit of R&D here! (ie: does the data table have to update specific rows matching on some column other then PK??

Comment: ya, my table do not have PK, just few column need match then update the record.  Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You certainly can pass a datatable into a SQL server SO using a table valued type parameter. The code shown in the question should work. Certainly the C# equivalent does - I use it all the time.

Comment: @DaleK I check the table pass in by select it and return back to front end, it have record in the dataset.  But not sure why it's not update the records.